# What is a difference between cross-lingual IR and multi-lingual IR?

Tags: information-retrieval

In papers usually **Cross-Lingual Information Retrieval** (**CLIR**) and **Multi-Lingual Information Retrieval** (**MLIR**) use equivalently or distinctly. I want to know is there any difference between these two terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169023X12000213) paper they differentiate between these two terms as follows:

> While CLIR is concerned with retrieval for given language pairs (i.e.
>   all the documents are given in a specific language and need to be
>   retrieved to queries in another language), MLIR is concerned with
>   retrieval from a document collection where documents in multiple
>   languages co-exist and need to be retrieved to a query in any
>   language. MLIR is thus inherently more difficult than CLIR.